# What water saving technology could I apply to this tap (pic below). I can't identify its gender

Tags: water, kitchens, sink

[image: tap]I tried amazon to find out, but i really couldn't figure out what water saving tech would be most helpful.[image: side] See the [Water Saving Tap Aerator](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Waternymph-Hibbent-Dual-function-360-Degree-Replacement/dp/B06XRJBSPF/ref=pd_rhf_ee_s_cp_0_2?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B06XR7BBLC&pd_rd_r=79KX1SWQB6KKH1BP2KNW&pd_rd_w=EoJav&pd_rd_wg=5KVSH&refRID=79KX1SWQB6KKH1BP2KNW&th=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I can't identify its gender**

That looks like a female (internal) threaded tap. It takes a male (external) threaded insert.

> **I really couldn't figure out what water saving tech would be most helpful**

If you unscrew the hex insert using an appropriate spanner/wrench you can check the thread size and order an appropriate insert.

Personally, I find **not** turning the tap fully on, and turning it off early are good water saving solutions. You could also fit a [service valve](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=plumbing+service+valve) under the basin or sink and turn that half off.

Comment: you can crank down the service valve if there is one. might not be obvious...